# How do I put a logo on an image using python openCV?

Tags: python, visual-studio, opencv

I have been doing a tutorial on python OpenCV and am trying to append a logo to the upper right-hand corner of a different image. I used print statements to localize the problem to the bitwise_and lines. I have copied the code verbatim from the site and it still does not work.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\imaxm\\Downloads\\terryRozier.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\imaxm\\Downloads\\scaryTerryLogo.jpg')
rows,cols,channels = img2.shape
roi = img1[0:rows, 0:cols ]
img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, mask = cv2.threshold(img2gray, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
img1_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi,roi, mask = mask_inv)
img2_fg = cv2.bitwise_and(img2,img2,mask = mask)
dst = cv2.add(img1_bg,img2_fg)
img1[0:rows, 0:cols ] = dst
cv2.imshow('res',img1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code gives me this error:

```
cv2.error: ..\..\..\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:241: error: (-215) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function cv::binary_op
```

Any ideas?
[Here is the logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BFIc.jpg)

[Here is the background picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoViC.jpg)

Comment: post an image and a logo. As a first guess it appears your image and logo have different datatypes

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You have a great start on a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Complete it by posting the images.  Please don't refer to an external site.

Comment: @kevinkayaks Posted. They are both jpeg's. The tutorial I was following used PNG's, not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: So I just tried using png images and it works as expected. Any idea why jpgs wouldn't work the same way?